# overscan ignored in raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, config.txt

I configured the pi screen to be horizontal (using display_rotate=1) but as you can see in the image the scree is not in full screen:
[image]

it start from about 1/4 from left of the screen
I use a manual hdmi configuration, so I guess i can't configure overscan. even if I try, raspberry pi will ignore it. 
Any way to fix it somehow?

Here is my configuration:

```
display_rotate=1
overscan_left=200
config_hdmi_boost=4
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_drive=2
hdmi_timings=1440 0 50 10 35 2560 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 50 0 198000000 0
hdmi_pixel_freq_limit=500000000
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
max_framebuffer_width=1440
max_framebuffer_height=2560
framebuffer_width=1440
framebuffer_height=2560
hvs_priority=0x32ff
framebuffer_depth=24
framebuffer_ignore_alpha=1
gpu_mem=192
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which model Pi (the Pi4 is different), but you appear to be labouring under a misapprehension.

`display_rotate=1` **DOES NOT** rotate the framebuffer.

Get rid of all the extraneous rubbish you put in `config.txt` and it should work.
It looks to me like the Pi is doing precisely what you asked it to do!

Comment: I remove everything from config.txt - I get a blank screen. This is Pi3. I found out that the minimum config for the screen to work is to put the followings (but after that, the screen still start from 1/4 of the screen as in the image): hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_drive=2
hdmi_timings=1440 0 50 10 35 2560 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 50 0 198000000 0
hdmi_pixel_freq_limit=500000000
display_rotate=1 (note, the display rotate is optional, I want the screen to be in landscape mode)